# Random number generator with different numbers

Tags: c#, random

I am currently working on one of my first projects in C#.
Right now i want to create something like a lottomachine.
It should output 6 numbers all different from each other in the range of 1-49.

```
private void random()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    z1 = rnd.Next(1, 49);
    z2 = rnd.Next(1, 49);
    if (z1 == z2)
    {
        z2 = rnd.Next(1, 49);
    }
    z3 = rnd.Next(1, 49);
    if ((z1 == z3) || (z2 == z3))
    {
        z3 = rnd.Next(1, 49);
    }
    z4 = rnd.Next(1, 49);
    if ((z1 == z4) || (z2 == z4) || (z3 == z4))
    {
        z4 = rnd.Next(1, 49);
    }
    z5 = rnd.Next(1, 49);
    if ((z1 == z5) || (z2 == z5) || (z3 == z5) || (z4 == z5))
    {
        z5 = rnd.Next(1, 49);
    }
    z6 = rnd.Next(1, 49);
    if ((z1 == z6) || (z2 == z6) || (z3 == z6) || (z4 == z6) || (z5 == z6))
    {
        z6 = rnd.Next(1, 49);
    }
}
```

The code is working for me currently, but I think there is a better, much shorter way what my code does. That's why I am asking for advice or for an idea, how to do it better than me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is not fully correct. You draw another random number if one collided with an already drawn one. But what if the second attempt also produces a collision?

Comment: Codereview would have been a better place https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have tested it now multiple times and never had the same number twice. So either my code is working or i was just lucky. If i was just lucky do you have a solution for this problem, because i havent got an idea how to do it otherwise

Comment: That chance of getting a duplicate is roughly 1/50, so the chance of getting two duplicates in a row is in the order of magnitude of 1/(50*50)=1/2500.

Comment: Notice you should change 49 to 50 the upper value is exclusive, you would never get 49.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve it would be to simulate what a real lotto machine does.

First, put the 49 balls in the bucket:

```
var bucket = Enumerable.Range(1, 49).ToList();
```

Then in a loop, determine a random **index** in the current bucket, get the number at this index and **remove it** so that it cannot be drawn again

```
var random = new Random();
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    var index = random.Next(bucket.Count);
    var number = bucket[index];
    Console.WriteLine(number);
    bucket.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple code with recursive call:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
List<int> listWinningnumbers = new List<int>();

        
for(int cont = 1; cont <= 6; cont++)
{
    SetNumbersWinners(listWinningnumbers);
}

private void SetNumbersWinners(List<int> listWinningnumbers)
{
    
    int luckynumber = rnd.Next(1, 49);

    if (listWinningnumbers.Exists(w => w == luckynumber))
    {
        SetNumbersWinners(listWinningnumbers);
    }
    else
    {
        listWinningnumbers.Add(luckynumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: You better use a single `Random` insatnce instead of gerenating a new one every time. Depending on the .NET version, this might otherwies end up in lots of collsions, because the pseudo-random generators are seeded from the current system time in .NET Framework.

Comment: Good. I changed as instructed.

Answer (score 0):

This example draws 6 unique random lotto numbers from a possible range of 1-49

```
class Program
{
    public static readonly Random rng = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Today's Lotto Numbers Are:");
        var lotto = DrawLotto(6);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", lotto));
        //42,23,4,46,8,43
    }

    public static int[] DrawLotto(int count, int maxNumber = 49)
    {
        // Generate lotto numbers sequentially.
        int[] result = Enumerable.Range(1, maxNumber).ToArray();
        // Generate random numbers between 0-1
        double[] random = result.Select((i) => rng.NextDouble()).ToArray();
        // Sort the lotto numbers using the random numbers for ordering
        Array.Sort(random, result);
        // Return the first 'count' numbers requested
        return result.Take(count).ToArray();
    }
}
```

I am using a 4 step process, as outlined in the comments of `DrawLotto()`. The idea is to create a shuffled array of all possible numbers in the drawing and return only the first 6. The shuffling process guarantees uniqueness and randomness. The above can easily be extended to other variations, but modyfing the `maxNumber` parameter, or the `count` argument.